# Un-initiated transaction

Tags: applications

I just received an email from Apple Support saying a purchase was made with my account from a previously unknown device. There was a note saying if you did not make this purchase, click here. When I clicked it, I was sent to a site that in no way was connected to this transaction. What can I do?

Comment: These mails are fake, best just to delete them. Did you enter any data on the site, or click on any additional links?

Comment: Thanks, good to know! And, whew, I did all the right things!

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a [phishing message](https://www.actionfraud.police.uk/phishing).

That means the sender is trying to collect your login and password. You should report this message as junk, delete it, and close it and any windows it opened.

If you've provided any details to the website thinking it was Apple you need to immediately change your password via https://appleid.apple.com

Also if you use this password on any other website you should consider these websites also vulnerable and should immediately change the password on all sites which use this password in the following order:

1. Email accounts + bank accounts
2. Social media
3. All other sites

Comment: If this is the answer to your question you should select the tick mark to indicate that, that way I get some points and the next person to come along with this question knows this question was already answered and doesn't answer it again.